# Combine first and last name and update into full name column for each row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

For each first and last name I would just like to combine and update them into the fullname column in the same "names" table.

This should happen for every row in the table. The columns are Id, FirstName, LastName and FullName.

Any help would be appreciated

```
update Names n 
set n.FullName = (
    select CONCAT(FirstName,' ',LastName)  
    from Names a 
    where n.Id = a.Id
)
where n.FullName is null 
and n.FirstName is not null and n.LastName is not null
```

Comment: You could use Update from Select like its explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This UPDATES FullName Colum that are blank or have NULL values.

```
UPDATE Names
SET FullName = ISNULL(FirstName + ' ','') +  ISNULL(LastName,'')
WHERE ISNULL(FullName,'') = ''
```

**EDIT**

```
UPDATE Names
SET FullName = FirstName + ' ' + LastName
WHERE ISNULL(FullName,'') = '' AND  ISNULL(FirstName,'') <> '' AND ISNULL(LastName,'') <> ''
```

Comment: I would like to skip the row if FirstName or LastName are null so I dont have full names with just first or last name

Comment: and n.FirstName is not null and n.LastName is not null

Comment: Looks Great! Thank you!